# Adding data into existing column SQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

Edit:
randomly searching through other languages i found the correct answer if anyone needs:
"update DataBase_Name set Column= '"+value+"' where ID='"+value+"';"

I need to insert data into a column and couldn't find much info about it on the web.

the code is

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {
             if (this->listBox1->SelectedIndex!=-1)
             {
String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = 
gcnew MySqlCommand(insert into products_shop.productname where idProductName='"+this-listBox1->SelectedItem->ToString()+"' ('ProductX','ProductY') values('"+this->textBox2-Text+","+this->textBox3->Text+"');",conDataBase);

                MySqlDataReader^ MyReader;
                try
                {
                conDataBase->Open();
                    MyReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
                }

                catch(Exception^ex)
                { 
                    MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
                }
             }
            else
                {
                     MessageBox::Show(L"Select an item please");
                }
         }

insert into products_shop.productname where idProductName='"+this->listBox1-SelectedItem-ToString()+"' ('ProductX','ProductY') values('"+this->textBox2-Text+","+this->textBox3-Text+"');
```

this line is just my randm guess, any help on how the syntax should actually be? or if it works somehow different..
thanks for help

Comment: Sounds like you need to use update instead of insert?

Comment: Without any sort of [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) this is dangerously bad code.